# Switching to another UIView, within TabBar

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, interface-builder

Here is my app setup.

TabBar App with three tab items, tabs 2 and 3 are irrelevant

The TabBarController is located within MainWindow.xib

In interface builder for MainWindow.xib, within the TabBarController
i have the seperate viewControllers for each tab.
Then a view for each view controller underneath ( this can been seen when viewing the object in list view)

The application loads and displays the first tab.
I want to be able to have a button in the view of the first tab that can be clicked that will then animate the following:
the current view fading out
a new view fading in within the SAME tab.
Would the new view require a new viewcontroller or just an additional view under the view controller? or can i create a new view controller and load that with its view?

how would i go about this? just the method is needed.

How would i go about this?  Thanks

EDIT

my interface builder list looks like this

[image: http://i51.tinypic.com/2i7vjv6.jpg]

Where should i place this new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the additional view controller. Just add additional view in current controller's view and that will be good enough. When user touch up on button make animation that will adjust transparency of views for desired duration. After animation is finished set transparent view as hidden so it won't capture the user actions.

```
@interface NewsletterViewController {
  IBOutlet UIView *view1;
  IBOUtlet UIView *view2;
}
```

In interface builder, add this views to NewsletterViewController->View and connect them with these outlets.

Some code for animation setup:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(onFadeFinished)];
view1.alpha = 0;
view2.alpha = 1
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You can place it inside the View that is in Selected Newsletter View Controller and you should add into your h file: IBOutlet UIView *view2 and connect it in interface builder with same class in File's Owner. view1 and view2 should be subviews of mentioned View.

Comment: I've had to rework the app slightly.. could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319584/tab-bar-controller-switch-uiview-within-one-tab