# Tab Bar Controller- switch UIView within one tab

Tags: xcode, animation, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, switch-statement

ok here is my applications setup:
Two xib's

MainWindow.xib
NewsletterView.xib

Set up as follows:
MainWindow.xib
Files owner
First Responder
The Delegate
Window
Tab Bar Controller--setup to load tabs from .xib's
 Two tabs -Newsletter
          -Map

I'm not concerned about the Map tab.

Within the NewsletterView.xib ( i do have the .h and .m files setup)

Files owner set up with class NewsletterViewController via interface builder.
First Responder
and Two views:
View- setup as NewsSignUpView via IBOutlet - this is the first view that loads on the selected tab.
View - setup as NewsReaderView via IBOutlet

I want to be able to click a button (assigned via IBAction) on NewsSignUpView the flip horizontally to reveal NewsReaderView.

This is what i have so far:

```
-(IBAction) revealNewsReaderView 
{CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:newsSignUpView cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This Flips the view but doesn't change the view shown.

Can anyone provide some code, or point out where im going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the apple's sample to see implementation of flipping between two views in same frame.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks, thats for flipping images in the same view, and from what i can understand thats creating the views programatically, i want to use one i have created in interfacebuilder and linked via IBOutlet

Comment: Ok with some fiddling i got it! Thanks for your help.